# Simple remote-controlled momentary switch

Tags: infrared, remote-control

I need to create a momentary switch which is controlled remotely, preferably through IR from an old TV remote control (if possible), in order to answer my office door buzzer without getting up.

On the panel for the buzzer, there is an unlock push button, which opens the door while you hold it pressed, and locks when you release it, so I would like to keep this functionality but add an IR receiver which would do the same in parallel.

So far, this is what I've found: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/IR-DC-5v-Remote-Control-Switch-1-Channel-Relay-Module-Board-With-1-key-Infrared-WirelessTransmitter/32654853261.html?spm=2114.40010308.4.148.9TTPdO

My problem is that the product is not sufficiently documented, so I'm worried about the exact pinout and wiring of the device. There is a pinout but it's in Chinese and is not documented properly. If anyone has had experience with one of these, could you please explain its pinout and functionality, so that I know what I'm buying and how I'm going to use it?

Comment: Since you have 100+ rep, you already know stackechange is not a forum. Try editing your question to ask something specific. "Any ideas" about how to do an entire project is not a good question.

Comment: Basic 38kHz IR transmitter (555) to basic 38kHz (TSOP) receiver with a BJT driver/relay tagged on the end.  - and I second @Bort - not a good question and I'll also add poorly researched as well.

Comment: Am I correct that a "basic 38kHz" receiver will trigger for *any* signal, not a specific button on the remote?

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/XIND-ELE-1CH-24V-DC-IR-Remote-Switch-Support-Connect-Button-Switch-2-key-Control-For/32699326738.html?spm=2114.40010308.4.2.KH14Sl

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/IR-DC-5V-Remote-Control-Switch-2-Channel-Jog-Inching-Relay-Module-Receiver-With-3-key/32655314277.html?spm=2114.10010108.1000013.3.ibdD3H&scm=1007.13339.33317.0&pvid=a4efb088-c4b9-4c97-8c9a-31d8465ab1b5&tpp=1

Comment: If you want a learning option to use an existing IR remote control: http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-Channel-Infrared-Remote-Control-Relay-Module-Learning-IR-Switch-5V-/222448326651?hash=item33caf417fb:g:-pwAAOSwsW9Y0orR     ....though why you couldn't do a simple search to find these seems strange.

Comment: I agree with you guys, it was a poorly documented question, I will edit it ASAP to explain it further and help anyone else who might come across this problem.